# Remove "title bar" at top of chrome

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, titlebar

I feel one of the biggest improvements with Chrome on Windows is moving the tabs all the way to the top to the screen (so the mouse can just go all the way up, then click). I went with the kubuntu because they do not include the normal (pointless) Linux menu bar at the top of the screen. It took me an hour to get chrome on here and now I see there is a Giant pointless title bar across the top. It is a good 5% of the total screen area and it is just the title and close buttons. Is there anyway to have the chrome tabs all the way at the top of the screen like was intended by Google?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Go to Chrome **Menu** ⇒ **Settings** ⇒ **Appearance** section, unmark *Use system title bar and borders*.

Comment: That didn't work with unity when at maximum size of the window.

Comment: It worked for me, on Linux Mint Mate.

Comment: Works for me on Manjaro with KDE Plasma. Thanks!

Comment: How to do this from console ???

Comment: Works for me too in the plasma desktop.

Comment: It works in Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04!

Comment: Also works for Ubuntu DDE 20.04

Comment: Also works for Kubuntu 20.04!

Comment: Worked. Kubuntu 22.04. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the latest build of Chromium, version 94 now, the **Menu ⇒ Settings ⇒ Appearance ⇒** **Use system title bar and borders** option is no longer available there.

What you need to do to access this option is **Right Click** in any **empty space** in the **Tab Bar** and select or deselect the **Use system title bar and borders** option from the drop down menu, as shown in the screenshots below below.

**Use system title bar and borders** option - ***Selected***:
[image: Use system title bar and borders - Selected]

**Use system title bar and borders** option - ***Deselected***:
[image: Use system title bar and borders - Deselected]

Answer (score 1):

Open system settings *(the `systemsettings` app)*, and go to `WorkSpace Appearance → Window Decorations → Configure Decoration`. Switch to the `Window-Specific Overrides` tab. There you have to add a new override, press `Add` button, you will see a new window with checkboxes. Press `Detect Windows Properties` button *(your mouse cursor will turn into aim like icon)*, and click at the Google Chrome window. You will be prompted of whether to use window class, or just title, choose the window class checkbox. Finally, check `Hide window title bar` checkbox, press ok.

Note that you can move windows by holding Alt key and clicking them.

Comment: In the System Settings of Kubuntu 16.04 LTS (KDE 5) the item "WorkSpace Appearance" is renamed to "Application Style".

Answer (score 1):

For those who also would like to **get rid of window buttons** (minimize, maximize, close).

Right-click the titlebar of Google Chrome, go to **More Actions** ⇒ **Configure Special Application Settings...** ⇒ **Appearance & Fixes** tab, mark **No titlebar and frame**, in the following menu select **Force** and then **Yes** on the right, click **OK** to save new settings.

If you need to access the window manager's menu in KDE (like right-clicking the titlebar), you can always use **Alt+F3** shortcut.